# How to save strings in a stringlist which is created in another procedure?

Tags: delphi, procedure, delphi-xe3, tstringlist

i need some help with my procedure. I want to save some strings in a stringlist which is created in another procedure. How can i do this?

I wrote a comment at the right place to understand it better.

```
procedure GetIniNamesWithoutExt(IniPfade: TStringList);
var
  i, suchPunkt: integer;
  ini: TIniFile;
  Modul, fullFileName, IniName: String;
begin
  try
  for i := 0 to IniPfade.Count-1 do
  begin
    fullFileName := IniPfade.Strings[i];
    Modul := ExtractFileName(fullFileName);  // Dateiname aktueller Ini + .Ini Endung
    suchPunkt := Pos('.', Modul);
    IniName := Copy(Modul, 1, suchPunkt-1);  // Aktueller Modulname ohne ini Endung
    // Here should be the Code for saving the String "IniName" to a StringList which is created in procedure a. Procedure a calls the procedure GetIniNamesWithoutExt.
  end;
  finally

  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your intention, but if you're going to save the modified string to the `IniPfade` string list passed as a parameter, simply do it by `IniPfade[i] := IniName;`, but I guess your question is about something else.

Comment: Ive created in another procedure "a" a stringlist and wanted to save my var IniName to the StringList which exist in procedure a...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
procedure GetIniNamesWithoutExt(IniPfade, Module: TStrings);
var
  i, suchPunkt: integer;
  ini: TIniFile;
  Modul, fullFileName, IniName: String;
begin
  Module.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to IniPfade.Count-1 do
    begin
      fullFileName := IniPfade.Strings[i];
      Modul := ExtractFileName(fullFileName);  // Dateiname aktueller Ini + .Ini Endung
      suchPunkt := Pos('.', Modul);
      IniName := Copy(Modul, 1, suchPunkt-1);  // Aktueller Modulname ohne ini Endung
      Module.Add(IniName);
    end;
  finally
    Module.EndUpdate;
  end;   
end;
```

and from procedure A:

```
procedure A;
var 
  Module: TStringList;
begin
  Module := TStringList.Create;
  try
    GetIniNamesWithoutExt(IniPfade , Module);
    // Do Whatever you want with "Module"
  finally
    Module.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I added a `try`..`finally` block for the `TStringList`.

Comment: Another option: To declare my StringList global and creating it in procedure a.

Comment: @Robin2k which I would advise against.

Comment: @Smasher, thanks for the addition - I was typing a bit hastily. Where there is a Create finally should be a Free !

Comment: @iamjoosy I just changed `TStringList` to `TStrings` and also added `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` for `Module`. Now it is possible to pass e.g. `TComboBox.Items` as Module parameter

Comment: Instead of the `Pos` and `Copy` to remove the extension, you can just use `ChangeFileExt(fullFileName, '');` instead.